# Can't upload file to server Laravel

Tags: php, file, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to add some products to my database and I have to upload photo of this product. I've made a controller and view but when I click Create I've got an error

```
Unable to create the "/uploads/products/" directory
```

Here is my code:
Controller

```
public function postAddProduct(){
    $destinationPath = '';
    $filename        = '';
    $newId = Product::max('id')+1;
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
        'name' => 'required',       
        'description' => 'required',            
        'partner_link' => 'required',
        'image'=>'required'
    ));
    if (Input::hasFile('image')) {
        $file            = Input::file('image');
        $destinationPath = public_path().'/uploads/products/';
        $filename        = $newId.'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $uploadSuccess   = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
    }

    if($validator->passes()){
        $product = new Product;
        $product->name = Input::get('name');
        $product->description = Input::get('description');
        $product->category_id = Input::get('category');
        $product->partner_link = Input::get('partner_link');
        $product->photo = $filename;
        $product->save();   

        return Redirect::back();
    }else{
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }



}
```

View:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'user/admin/products/addd', 'files' => true, 'class'=>'col-md-4', 'style'=> 'float:none; margin: 0 auto', 'id'=>'register-form')) }}
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Add Product</h2>    
            {{ Form::text('name', null, array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Name')) }}    
            {{ Form::textarea('description', null, array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Description')) }}
            {{ Form::text('partner_link', null, array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Partner link')) }}
            {{Form::label('category', 'Category: ', array('class' => 'field-name'))}}
            <select name="category">
                <?php $i = 0; ?>
                @foreach($categories as $category)      
                    <optgroup label="{{$category['name']}}">
                    @foreach($category['subcategories'] as $sub)
                        <option value="{{$sub->id}}">{{$sub->name}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                    </optgroup>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>                
            {{Form::file('image', array('style' => 'margin-bottom: 10px'))}}
            {{ Form::submit('Add', array('class'=>'btn btn-large btn-primary btn-block'))}}
        {{ Form::close() }}
```

**Update**

Current `bootstrap/paths.php` file:

```
return array(       
    'app' => __DIR__.'/../app',
    'public' => __DIR__.'/../public',
    'base' => __DIR__.'/..',
    'storage' => __DIR__.'/../app/storage',  
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the `public/uploads/products` folder does not exist, and Laravel does not have permission to create it.

Try create the folder manually, make sure Laravel has writable access to it by running `chmod 775 public/uploads/products` . Then try the code again.

Comment: I have this folder in public_html/ cause this application is on server.

Comment: What's the path to your Laravel project? How do you integrate public_html into Laravel? E.g. symbolic linking the public folder? Or the whole Laravel structure goes into public_html, e.g. public_html/app, public_html/bootstrap, ... ?

Comment: No, this is my structure of app in public_html I've got all js/css/images files http://i57.tinypic.com/rc0bw1.png

Comment: I assume that you've configured your custom folder into Laravel already (i.e. in bootstrap/paths.php). Then you just create folder `public_html/uploads/products`.

Comment: my bootstrap looks like this `return array(


 'app' => __DIR__.'/../app',



 'public' => __DIR__.'/../public',



 'base' => __DIR__.'/..',

 
 'storage' => __DIR__.'/../app/storage',

);`
Sorry for styling.

Comment: You'll need `'public' => __DIR__.'/../public_html'`.

Comment: Okey I dont have an error but I dont have image in folder too.

Comment: Try `chmod 775 public_html/uploads/products`. Or 777 if 775 does not work.